# What does "G/W" refer to In context of XML Middleware

Tags: xml

I am an interpreter who's about to participate in conference call between two different IT solution developing companies regarding linking two CRM solution using SOAP protocol.

While reviewing the topic-related mails between two parties, I have found a team name called "Middle-ware XML G/W"

The question is:

**What does G/W refer to in this context?**

Comment: A couple of Google search indicate it means "gateway", in this context. See http://www.acronymfinder.com/GW.html. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming and is thus inappropriate for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML G/W** stands for ***XML gateway***.

For more information on XML gateways, see:

- [Are XML Gateways Really the Answer?](http://atownley.org/2006/06/are-xml-gateways-really-the-answer/)
- [Introducing Oracle XML Gateway](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12166_01/web/B12099_01/adx17gat.htm)
- [Cisco ACE XML Gateway](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/application-networking-services/ace-xml-gateway/model.html)